# How to configure new Server Key on Twilio using Firebase cloud messaging for push notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, twilio

following the Twilio documentation here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/configure-android-push-notifications#step-5-upload-your-api-key-to-twilio I just noticed that firebase changed its Server Key method to use its Api.

Actually I see this screen:
[image]

While on Twilio documentation I see this:
[image]

How can I obtain or generate the new key Twilio needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to use the Server key listed under *Cloud Messaging API (legacy)* for now.

Comment: The Cloud Messaging API is deprecated and disabled by default now. It indicates that you must migrate if already on it by mid-next year. Is there another way to do this now? Are web push certificates valid?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know and I no longer work at Twilio. Your best bet is likely to open a new question asking how to do it now that the old method is fully deprecated.